# Angular-translate: translate different portions of the page with different languages

Tags: angularjs, localization, angular-translate

I'm writing a web application using AngularJS 1.4.x and I'm using "[angular-translate](https://angular-translate.github.io/)" as localization library.

The app supports 2 languages: English and French.

The user can switch between these two languages and the application is localized accrodingly.

Now I have the following request: I need to localize all the application with  a "main language", let's say English but I need to  localize a small portion of the app in the other language (French).

The two languages must co-exists, so for example the header of the application is in English but the content of the page is in French, please see the attached image:

[image]

How can I do that? Is it possible with this library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to make your own translate filter which will wrap the angular translate.

```
app.filter('mytranslation', ['$translate', '$filter', function($translate, $filter) {
 return function(input, lang) {
  input = input || '';
  var currentLanguage = $translate.use();
  $translate.use(lang);
  var result = $filter("translate")(input);
  $translate.use(currentLanguage);
  return result;
```

}
}])

And then in the html page you can use it as:

```
 <p>German section</p>
```

{{'HELLO' | mytranslation:'de'}}

Here is a working example: https://plnkr.co/edit/pYFo3Wapz12Q6686zrqn?p=preview

Comment: I accept your answer because it solved my problem. I want only to highlight that `$translate.use(lang);` is an async operation and it can take a while. So the next line `var result = $filter("translate")(input);` can be executed *before* the language has been changed. To solve this, the method `$translate.use(lang);` returns a promise that can be used to know when the language has been successfully changed.